# ¿Qué dicen en este fragmento de serie? ¿Está diciendo "Dime, ¿estás... queardas?"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, identificación-de-término

En 14:36 de [este programa](https://youtu.be/POG8X5meji4?t=868), ¿qué dice el chico?

> Dime, ¿estás... queardas?  // ¿que ardas?

Siempre lo oigo, me parece que signifique "estás listo" pero no estoy seguro porque nunca he descubierto como escribir esa palabra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estoy bastante seguro de que lo que dice el chico es:

> Dime, ¿estás que ardes, Natsu?

<sub>Nótese el debate sobre Nacho, Natxo, Natsu en los comentarios.</sub>

La expresión *estar que arde* puede tener bastantes connotaciones, todas ellas indicando intensidad de una sensación y equivalentes a *estar al rojo vivo*.

Por ejemplo, decimos:

> En esa serie los personajes principales intentan seducirse el uno al otro. Últimamente la cosa está que arde, ¡yo creo que en breve se acabarán liando!

Pero también puede utilizarse en contextos no erótico-amorosos, sino también de enojo:

> Al chico le han estafado por internet. ¡Está que arde! Como encuentre al ladrón no sé qué le hará.

En definitiva, la expresión es usada para denotar situaciones de alta carga de amor-odio. Como no tengo ni idea de qué va esta serie, no puedo aventurar el significado exacto en este contexto.

Comment: También se puede usar "está que arde" en referencia a hechos o situaciones, por ejemplo: "La situación en X país está que arde" (muy complicada, a punto de explotar).

Comment: Nombre (por lo menos como se escribe en inglés) es Natsu =D