# Transcripción de este video de Chapulín Colorado

Tags: méxico, identificación-de-término

Anyone that knows Mexican Spanish can transcribe what they say in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQBjn0WGVRY&t=17m53s) from the minute 17m53s to 18m03s?

What I can understand:

> Chapulin: ____ el principio del romance *(es lo que puedo entender, no sé si está correcto, quiero saber si alguien lo entiende)*
>
> Perico: ¡Las dos cosas!
>
> Chapulin: Las dos cosas, las dos cosas, es lo unico que sabes decir o me estás _____ *(no conozco la palabra "hacillando", no sé si es correcta y no encuentro un sentido para ella apenas buscando)*
>
> Perico: ¡Las dos cosas!

Comment: Hello Marcos, and welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Do you have any idea about what they are saying? If you can identify some parts of the speech you can add them to your question, and leave blanks for the parts you don't understand, so we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question! I have voted to reopen it, but meanwhile I can comment here that I can't understand what Chapulín says in the first sentence, but in the second sentence he says "vacilando", from "[vacilar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bEjxKUN)" in its 5th meaning: "Engañar, tomar el pelo, burlarse o reírse de alguien." So he's asking the parrot if he's mocking him.

Comment: I would not recommend this kind of videos to learn Spanish but I voted to reopen the now modified question.  The first word will only be guessed by a Mexican but the sentences goes "¿Es ____ o principio de romance?" and in the second part the word is *vacilando* as in @Charlie comment.

Comment: Reabro esta pregunta es tras los edits. No es distinta a otras que tenemos como [¿Qué dicen en este fragmento de serie?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20329/5481). Desafortunadamente, al visitar el enlace se obtiene un error: `Video unavailable
This video contains content from univision, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds.` No sé si soy solo yo o les pasa a otros usuarios

Comment: @Diego yo sí puedo verlo. Bien por reabrirla, estoy de acuerdo en que ahora sí es _on-topic_.

Comment: Creo que _banearon_ a @Diego en YouTube jajaja. Yo también puedo ver el video. Muchas veces nos toca en latinoamérica usar servidores proxy para acceder a contenido que solo está disponible en USA pero en este caso parece que es al contrario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Chapulín: ¡Ay! ¡qué! ¡pues qué! ¿Es pleito o principio de romance?
- Perico: Las dos cosas, las dos cosas.
- Chapulín: "Las dos cosas, las dos cosas", ¿Es lo único que sabes decir o me estás vacilando?
- Perico: Las dos cosas...

What people generally underestand when using those terms in México:

Pleito: To get into an argument, row or fight. It can get physical or not but very heated anyway. In other contexts it can be used to describe different scenarios like a legal conflict, you may want to read [the RAE definition](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TOyIWON) to expand on it for the other cases.

*Vacilando* from the verb "vacilar": It has many interpretations depending on the context, but in this case is certainly **to tease someone**.

Comment: Bienvenido/a. Excelente oído. Lo intenté varias veces pero la palabra **pleito** nunca la pude entender. Obvio ahora despues de tu respuesta la entiendo perfecto. +1

Comment: Thank you very much. Very well done, I would never guessed or listened es pleito o principio de romance... You help me very much!